# Operator overload - float+self defined object

Tags: python, operator-overloading

```
class Point:
  def __init__(self, x = 0.0, y = 0.0)
    self.x = float(x)
    self.y = float(y)
  def __add__(self, f)
    return(self.x + f, self.y + f)
```

This code can operate `Point + float`.

How do I operate `float + Point`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By defining [`__radd__()`](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__radd__) as well.